# CheckBox isCheked returns true but visually is not checked

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I'm trying to initialize a checkbox listview from an array.
To do so I'm looping through listview items and checking if the item exists or doesn't, if it does then I set it to checked. Thing is it doesn't really work as expected. Internally everything works just fine, the result array is correct, but visually it doesn't display the checkboxes in their correct state.

This is the function which initializes the checkboxes, it is called by onCreate and onResume methods.

```
public void init()
{
    View v;
    CheckBox checkbox;
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST.getCount(); i++) {
        v = LIST.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
        checkbox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        MyClass c = (MyClass) adapter.getItem(i);
        if(List_to_compare.contains(c)) {
            Log.i("Before", String.valueOf(checkbox.isChecked())); //returns false
            checkbox.setChecked(true);
            Log.i("After", String.valueOf(checkbox.isChecked())); //returns true
        }
    }
}
```

But the checkbox is not visually checked. If more code is needed, let me know, really struggling with this one.

Comment: you can add an xml to check if checkbox is good configurated. Code looks fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing isn't going to work.

When you call `getView()` and change the view, the `ListView` has no idea that you changed that view.  The `ListView` itself calls `getView()` to render list items and it's going to ignore anything you've done.

Here's how to fix it:

Instead of calling `getView()`, you will *override* `getView()` in your adapter and have lines of code such as:

```
    checkbox = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
    MyClass c = (MyClass) getItem(position);
    checkbox.setChecked(List_to_compare.contains(c));
```

For future reference, any change to a `ListView` item should be made to a model of the item in the adapter before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`, and the that item model should be used in `getView()` to display the current state.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation kris, I knew I needed to notify the list about the changed somehow.
I still haven't figured out how to solve my problem thought. That Array of booleans you mention is kind of my List_to_compare array, since the ones that are not there will not be checked.

Comment: I guess all thats left to be done to make it work as you proposed is to implement the setItemChecked method, right?

Comment: So the checkbox is display only?  Nothing changes if user clicks on it? I just assumed that you did something when the checkbox was checked and that you hadn't posted code for that.

Comment: Kind of, think of a listview of checkboxes to select items from a list. All my struggle is to initialize the list with the selected items once you come back to the list (2nd time and on)

Comment: I updated my answer, maybe it's still not accurate but the point is, you determine the current state of the checkbox in `getView()` and set it there.  If you are tracking when the user is (un)checking the checkbox, you need to store the new state in the adapter somewhere and read it in `getView()`.

Comment: Oh finally I understood what you meant! Now it is working just fine :)
I now initialize the listview from getView() method rather than initializing it on false and checking it from outside. I think this one is a better approach.
Thank you kris for helping me out!